# Returning an array of objects from GetStaticProps in NextJS and using map function to iterate over it

Tags: javascript, next.js, javascript-objects, nextjs-dynamic-routing, getstaticprops

I am building a mdx blog in NextJS. For this I have created a function getPostDataByCategory(category) in posts.js under lib to filtering posts based on category.

```
getPostDataByCategory(category) {
const fileNames = fs.readdirSync(postsDirectory);
// allPostsData to read all the file contents parsed using gray-matter
const allPostsData = fileNames.map((fileName) => {
...
}
let filteredPosts = [];

  filteredPosts.push(
    allPostsData.filter((post) => post.categories.includes(category))
  );

  return { filteredPosts };
}
```

I am receiving the filteredPosts in getStaticProps in  categories/[categories].js as under:

```
export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
let posts = await getPostDataByCategory(params.categories);
  const filteredPosts = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(posts));

  return {
    props: {
      filteredPosts,
    },
  };
}
```

Thereafter I receive the filteredPosts in Category as:

```
export default function Category({ filteredPosts }) {
  
  return (
    <Layout>
      <ul>
        {filteredPosts.map((posts) => (
          <li key={posts.slug}>
            <p>{posts.title}</p>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </Layout>
  );
}
```

However it gives me an error as **TypeError: filteredPosts.map is not a function**

I understand this error is due to the fact that filteredPosts is not an array and object destructing has to be done or it has to be converted to an array.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks beforehand.

I searched extensively for converting the array of Objects to array of arrays but they all seem complex for my usecase. There must be a simpler way of doing this.

Comment: Seems like you need `filteredPosts.filteredPosts.map(...)`? Does it work if you do that?

Comment: Nope. Still does not work

Comment: What does logging `filteredPosts` before `return { props: { filteredPosts } }` show you?

Comment: When logging it shows { filteredPosts: [ [ [Object], [Object] ] ] }. It shows two Objects as there are 2 posts being filtered. typeof(filteredPosts) shows 'object' type

Comment: Thanks, what about logging `filteredPosts` inside of your `Category` component? What does that show?

Comment: same as in getStaticProps, i.e. { filteredPosts: [ [ [Object], [Object] ] ] }

Comment: Hm, I really would've thought then that `filteredPosts.filteredPosts.map()` is what you're after. Does `Array.isArray(filteredPosts.filteredPosts)` show true or false?

Comment: It shows true. Please elaborate how filteredPosts.filteredPosts.map() will work. Better provide a code snippet for mapping using  filteredPosts.filteredPosts.map(). On logging filteredPosts.filteredPosts I am able to get the data. Just the mapping part I am not clear about.

Comment: `filteredPosts.filteredPosts.map()` shouldn't result in the typeerror you're getting then if it's an array (as arrays have a `.map()` method). The reason why you need to "access" `filteredPosts` twice is because inside of `getStaticProps()` your variable that you've called `filteredPosts` is an object with a `filteredPosts` key in it. So when you destructure the prop `filteredPosts` from inside of component, the `filteredPosts` variable holds that object with the `filteredPosts` key.

Comment: Currently I am using mapping as <ul>
        {filteredPosts.filteredPosts.map(({ post }) => (
          <li key={post.slug}>
            <p>{post.title}</p>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul> and it is giving me error as "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'title')"

Comment: Please check edited comment above

Comment: Yes, now that's a different error. The error is about reading `title` of `undefined`. If you look at your data, the element inside of your `filteredPosts` array is `[ [Object], [Object] ]`. So that's what the first argument will be in your `.map()` callback. Destructuring using `{post}` won't work, as your elements in the array you're mapping (`filteredPost.filteredPosts`) is an array. I'm not sure if your inner objects have a `post` property on them either. Perhaps you really want: `filteredPosts.filteredPosts.flat().map(post => ...)`,  so we flatten the array to remove the nested array.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That worked perfectly. Please, if possible, share a link to read about it in detail. Thanks again.

Comment: I'll add an answer, as most of this can be avoided by fixing the code in `getPostDataByCategory`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing up object key names and also pushing nested arrays where it's not needed, causing confusion and issues with your mapping operations. Most of the fixes can be made to `getPostDataByCategory` to clean up how your date is structured.

Firstly, the [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method returns a new array, so the below code says to push an array (the one returned by your `filter()`) into the `filteredPosts` array:

```js
let filteredPosts = [];

filteredPosts.push(
  allPostsData.filter((post) => post.categories.includes(category)) // push a new array into th `fileredPosts` array
);
```

This ends up with you having nested arrays which isn't what you want here. You just need to assign `fileredPost` directly to the result of `.filter()`:

```js
const filteredPosts = allPostsData.filter((post) => post.categories.includes(category));
```

Next, you then return an object with a `filteredPosts` key:

```js
return { filteredPosts };
```

This is equivalent to returning an object like so (see [short-hand property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#property_definitions)):

```js
return { filteredPosts: filteredPosts};
```

So your object has a `filteredPosts` posts *key*, that holds the array that's in the `filteredPosts` variable. Since you're returning just one thing (ie: the filtered posts), you can avoid creating the object so that now your `getPostDataByCategory` returns an array:

```js
return filteredPosts;
```

With these changes made to `getPostDataByCategory`, you can now update how `getStaticProps` is used (see code comments):

```js
export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  const filteredPosts = getPostDataByCategory(params.categories); // you don't need to `await` the `getPostDataByCategory()` as it isn't `async` and doesn't return a Promise.
  
  // No need to create a deep copy: const filteredPosts = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(posts));

  return {
    props: {
      filteredPosts, // filteredPosts is now an array of objects
    },
  };
}
```

Now you can map your `filteredPosts` correctly as you were trying to do:

```js
{filteredPosts.map((posts) => (
  <li key={posts.slug}>
    <p>{posts.title}</p>
  </li>
))}
```